# how the message broker can hold client side program when program reached to the end function and still run well?

Tags: c, go, rabbitmq, network-programming

i have still unclear how the message broker can hold the client side
let say in here

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
     amqp "github.com/streadway/amqp"
     "log"
     "time"
)

func failOnError(err error, msg string) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicf("%s: %s", msg, err)
     }
}

func main() {
    conn, err := amqp.Dial("amqp://user:user@localhost:5672/")
    failOnError(err, "Failed to connect to RabbitMQ")
    defer conn.Close()

    ch, err := conn.Channel()
    failOnError(err, "Failed to open a channel")
    defer ch.Close()

    q, err := ch.QueueDeclare(
        "task_queue", // name
        true,         // durable
        false,        // delete when unused
        false,        // exclusive
        false,        // no-wait
        nil,          // arguments
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to declare a queue")

    err = ch.Qos(
        1,     // prefetch count
        0,     // prefetch size
        false, // global
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to set QoS")
    //var forever chan struct{}

    msgs, err := ch.Consume(
        q.Name, // queue
        "",     // consumer
        false,  // auto-ack
        false,  // exclusive
        false,  // no-local
        false,  // no-wait
        nil,    // args
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to register a consumer")

    // focus at here
    for d := range msgs {
        log.Printf("Received a message: %s", d.Body)
        dotCount := bytes.Count(d.Body, []byte("."))
        t := time.Duration(dotCount)
        time.Sleep(t * time.Second)
        log.Printf("Done")
        d.Ack(false)
    }

}
```

in C on socket programming as we know that need an event loop to hold the message until the message is received using recv and using non blocking i/o like epoll etc. but in this higher language like Go
this `consumer.go` will hold on the program and if the message is published then the program will go back to the loop at "`for d := range msgs { ... }`", and i also debug this before publishing the message and that will reach the end program and the program still running well and not stopped

my question is, how do the client side hold the entire program when the program already reached to the end and then back to the loop when a message has already published ?

this applies also with other high level languages like JavaScript and Python, i just want to know how the low level work for this

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. With Go langage, child threads are closed when main function is finished. You must use "select{}" to block the main function : https://go.dev/play/p/9s4XJVtqN3l